# In HTML table, how to override font-size (alerady set at row-level) at cell-level?

Tags: html, html-table

I have an HTML table which has a row with font size set as 10:

```
<tr style="font-size: 10 px">
```

In this row, I have several cells; all of these would inherit the font-size set at row level shown above.

But I would like to override the font size in the above row and I would like to do that only for a few cells (and not all).

I tried overriding the font size at cell level as shown below:

```
<td style="font-size: 12 px">
```

But unfortunately the above overriding does not seem to take effect and I still see all cells in the above row with `font-size 10` only.

How can I achieve this overriding?

Please, help!

Comment: can you please post the code of your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey use important keyword with this!

```
<td style="font-size: 12 px; important;">
```

Answer (score 3):

The `!important` rule at the end of a value will **override** any other style declarations of that attribute, *including inline styles*.

```css
tr {
  font-size: 10px;
}

td {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome, If it works can I consider green tick from you, because to whom you have gave the green tick, have copied my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use style.css instead inline style.

```
<table class="my-table">
        <tr">
            <td>1 Сell 1 Row</td>
            <td class="accent-cell">2 Сell 1 Row</td>
            <td>3 Сell 1 Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 Сell 2 Row</td>
            <td>2 Сell 2 Row</td>
            <td>3 Сell 2 Row</td>
        </tr>            
</table>
```

In style.css define:

```
.my-table tr{
    font-size: 10px;
}

.my-table .accent-cell{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```